# Storing ragged (variable length) arrays objects w/ pytables

Tags: python, data-analysis, pytables

I'll preface this question by noting that I'm happy to consider alternatives to pytables, but I would prefer to use pytables in order to benefit from the numexpr features.

I'm looking for a solution for storing/exploring/analyzing my data, for example of the following form: suppose I have many `Event` objects, representing some experimental measurement at a certain instant in time. Each `Event` contains some scalar fields, as well as a *variable number* of `Particle` objects, each of which contain some scalar fields of their own. See my "drawing" below.

My first thought was to have each `Event` as a row in a table. I understand that there is a `VLArray` type in pytables, but it seems that these can only store primitive data types. Is there some way to store this data with pytables?

I also considered having each `Event` be its own group, with a `Particle` table containing a variable number of rows. However, I anticipate many millions of `Events`, and I would like to be able to e.g. select events and plot certain fields, as one would do with rows in a table.

If it's not possible to accomplish this with pytables, what are some alternative solutions?

```
    +-------------------------+
  +-------------------------+ |
+--------- Event ---------+ | |
|  timestamp    (int)     | | |
|  temperature  (float)   | | |
|  latitude     (float)   | | |
|  longitude    (float)   | | |
|  ... [etc]...           | | |
|                         | | |
|  +-- Particle<1> --+    | | |
|  |  idx    (int)   |    | | |
|  |  energy (float) |    | | |
|  |  x      (float) |    | | |
|  |  y      (float) |    | | |
|  |  z      (float) |    | | |
|  |  ... [etc] ...  |    | | |
|  +-----------------+    | | |
|          ...            | | |
|  +-- Particle<N> --+    | | |
|  |  idx    (int)   |    | | |
|  |  energy (float) |    | | |
|  |  x      (float) |    | | |
|  |  y      (float) |    | | |
|  |  z      (float) |    | | |
|  |  ... [etc] ...  |    | | +
|  +-----------------+    | +
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it database-style, with two tables.  One for Events:

```
    +-------------------------+
  +-------------------------+ |
+--------- Event ---------+ | |
|  timestamp    (int)     | | |
|  temperature  (float)   | | |
|  latitude     (float)   | | +
|  longitude    (float)   | +
+-------------------------+
```

And one for Particles, with a "foreign key":

```
    +-------------------------+
  +-------------------------+ |
+-------- Particle -------+ | |
|  event        (?)       | | |
|  idx          (int)     | | |
|  energy       (float)   | | |
|  x            (float)   | | |
|  z            (float)   | | +
|  ... [etc] ...          | +
+-------------------------+
```

The type of `Particle.event` could be an `int` index into an `Events` table, or it could be matched to an `id` column added to `Events`, or it could even be an `object` type which is actually a pointer to an `Event`.  They all have different trade-offs.

You could also "de-normalize" by copying the `Event` data into every `Particle` record.  This may provide better performance for some use cases, at the expense of some redundancy in the stored data.